# Python: Check when a cmd command completes its job

Tags: python, real-time

When I execute a python script using `subprocess.Popen(script, shell=True)` in **another** python script, is it possible to alert python when the script completes running before executing other functions?

On a side note, can I get real-time output of the executed python script?
I can only get output from it doing `command>output.txt` but that's only after the whole process ends. `stdout` does not grep any ouput.

Comment: Do you want that the original process that spawned the subprocess is notified? Or is there a separate process that monitors the script execution?

In other words: are you just looking for a simple "wait until script executes" or do you want to run a Python script in parallel to the subprocess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a subprocess with Popen, it returns a `subprocess.Popen` object that has several methods for accessing subprocess status and data:

- You can use `poll()` to determine whether a subprocess has finished. `None` indicates that the process has ended.
- Output from a script while its running can be retrieved with `communicate()`.

You can combine these two to create a script that monitors output from a subprocess and waits until its ready as follows:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen((["python", "script.py"]), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while p.poll() is None:
    (stdout, stderr) = p.communicate()
    print stdout
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to wait for the Popen to end? have you tried simply this:

```
popen = subprocess.Popen(script, shell=True)
popen.wait()
```

Have you considered using the external python script importing it as a module instead of spawning a subprocess?

As for the *real-time output*: try `python -u ...`